# Term not evaluated to a function in C++

Tags: c++

I have following code, which i taken from Boost and simplified for my project. Please accept my aplogies for pasting complete code, i done it so that it will be easy to answer my question. While compiling following code in VS 2008 i am getting followoing error.

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments
```

I am expecting addOptions retruns OptionsInit object which call function operator with three arguments but that is not happening, can any one please find bug. Thanks in advance.

```
namespace MyInfrastructure
{
namespace Internal
{
    class OptionDescrp;
    class OptionsInit;
}

class OptionsCollection
{
public:

    OptionsCollection(std::string optCollName);
    Internal::OptionsInit addOptions();

private:

    // avoid copying and assignment.
    // Prohibit copy
    OptionsCollection( const OptionsCollection& );
    OptionsCollection& operator = (const OptionsCollection& );

    void add(Internal::OptionDescrp* desc) {m_options.push_back(desc);}

    std::vector<Internal::OptionDescrp* > m_options;
    std::string m_optCollName;

    friend class Internal::OptionsInit;
};
}

////////////

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>
#include "PrgmOptions.h"


namespace MyInfrastructure
{
namespace Internal
{

class OptionDescrp 
{
public:

    OptionDescrp(std::string pcOptname, std::string description, bool isOptValueReq);
    virtual ~OptionDescrp(){ };

private:

    std::string m_shortName;  // option short name.
    std::string m_longName;   // option long name.
    std::string m_description;// option description.
};

class OptionsInit
{
public:
    OptionsInit(OptionsCollection* coll){ owner = coll; }
    OptionsInit& operator()(std::string name, std::string description, bool isOptValReq);

private:
    OptionsCollection* owner;
};

}

/////

namespace MyInfrastructure
{
    OptionsCollection::OptionsCollection(std::string optCollName) : m_optCollName(optCollName) {}

    Internal::OptionsInit OptionsCollection::addOptions()
    {       
        return Internal::OptionsInit(this);
    }
}

namespace MyInfrastructure
{
namespace Internal
{
    // Class Options description definitions.
    OptionDescrp::OptionDescrp(std::string pcOptname, std::string description, bool isOptValueReq)
                                : m_description(description)
    {
        std::string name(pcOptname);
        std::string::size_type n = name.find(',');
        if (n != std::string::npos) 
        {
            assert(n == name.size()-2);
            m_longName  = name.substr(0, n);
            m_shortName = '-' + name.substr(n+1,1);
        }
        else
        {
            m_longName = name;
        }
    }

    // Class Options Init definitions.
    OptionsInit& OptionsInit::operator()(std::string name, std::string description, bool isOptValReq)
    {
        OptionDescrp* opt = new OptionDescrp(name, description, isOptValReq);
        owner->add(opt);
        return *this;
    }
}
}

//////


int main(void)
{
    MyInfrastructure::OptionsCollection desc("myoptions");

    **desc.addOptions()("help", "produce help message", false); // error is thrown here**

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code example is incomplete - you're missing a closing brace before "/////" line; after fixing that and adding #include <string> #include <vector> at the beginning, the code compiles fine in MSVC2008 (2009 version does not exist) and GCC.

Comment: First, the error message doubtless came with a line number, but I don't see a line indicated.  Please point out which line got the error.  Also, you wrote VS 2009.  Did you mean VS 2008?

Comment: i am still getting the error, i am using VS2008

Comment: I'm getting the same results as @zeuxcg -- after adding a closing brace so you're not trying to define another MyInftrastracture inside of MyInfrastructure, it compiles fine. My first thougth is that perhaps you need to apply SP1 to your copy of VC++?

Comment: i have this code in different files, while pasting here i pasted continioulsy, is this makes any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code in the question compiles without errors with Visual 2008, gcc, Visual 2003 when we copy all in a single file.
You have error C2064, it is probably because you either have a #define or another definition somewhere in other headers that you did not include in your sample, or that somehow you are not compiling exactly the sample code.
Try to copy all the sample code in a single file and compile that.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting code: OptionsInit returned by addOptions() is a temporary. You are then calling a non-const method on it, which is allowed, but it returns a non-const reference to itself which is also allowed because it's a non-const method. But that means essentially you "backdoor" binding a non-const reference to a temporary...

I assume the two asterisks before desc.addOptions are not really in your code as there is no operator* overloaded here.

Perhaps if you make operator() const and return const-reference it will work.

Comment: hi, i made changes as you suggested still i am facing same error. Two asterisks in code is to show the error line. Any more suggestions? Thanks

Comment: this pattern is used in boost, it allows writing something like: desc.addOptions()("help", "produce help message", false)("option1", "do option1", true)("option2", "do option2", false)

Comment: i tried to use same way, but it is not compiling, i ma getting error not evaluated to function with 3 arguments

Answer (score 0):

problem is with VS2008. I compiled with VS2010, it compiled fine. Thanks all for the inputs.

Comment: i think vs2008 sp1 it compiles and it also compiled with VS2010.